# Which type of variable are week numbers?

Tags: r, discrete-data

I have a dataset where measurements on animals were done on multiple weeks of experiments. So I have measurements for week 1, week 2, etc. So I was wondering which type of variables are these? I thought they are discrete variables but I wanted to have a confirmation.
Also, with discrete variables can I make the same types of tests in R that you can make with continuous variables? e.g. t-tests

Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to do? What is your goal?

Comment: The idea was to see if there is some link between the week through the experiment and the severity of body lesions on animals. The body lesions would be scored on a scale from 0 to 5.